# Which is the right word to ask if this will create problem on a professional tone

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, email

I'm drafting a mail to my team informing them that I'm taking leave on some day and that I want to know if this will create problems or friction in working.

I used

> I’ll will be taking leave on June 18th (wednesday), please let me know if
>   this *might* cause any inconvenience to business operations.

I'm not sure if this is correct, as the word *'might'* seems out of order. I replaced it with *could*, *will*, and *can*, but I'm still not sure which to choose.

Comment: I'd go with *would* or *will* in there instead.

Comment: Also, start out with "I will" instead of "I'll will."

Comment: Either `I'll` or `I will`, but not both, since "I'll" is a contraction of "I will".

Comment: Also, are you leaving temporaily (as for a vacation) or permanently? I think "take leave" denotes a long time. If you're just going on holiday, say "I'll be leaving for vacation on June 18". Finally, Americans usually say "June 18", not "June 18th".

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I thought vacation indicated long times while leave is used for short period

Comment: "Leaving" is typically permanent, "taking leave" is for a short period (1 to a few days), "vacation/holiday" is typically a longer period (more than a week), "sabbatical" is an even longer period (several months).  Though just to be awkward "leaving" is also valid for immediate contexts, where you're going to be back the next day; you need context to disambiguate.

Comment: @Barmar comment and Miral comment are contary to each other! Maybe in future I have use "I will take 1 day leave on 07/11/14"

Comment: @ Downvoter thanks for not letting me know the reason why its down voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more assertive and professional tone would be:

> I will be out of office on June 18th ( Wednesday). Please let me know if it causes any inconvenience to business operations. If such is the case, I can plan a different date.

Or if you need that leave urgently and can not alter it under any circumstances, then do not leave the matter open for discussion. It should be something like this:

> I will be out of office on June 18th ( Wednesday). For urgent matters you can get in touch with me at (your mobile number).

Comment: Well OOO is simple it never occured to me thanks :)